# Mongodb: last N records, skip collection size - 30?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

**Simple:**

```
models.Message.find({ chat_id: req.params.chat_id }).skip(80).limit(30).sort({sent:1}).exec(function(err, message) {
    if(err) {
        res.json({error: 'Message not found.'});
    } else {
        res.json(message);
    }
});
```

How can I write `skip()` to skip the entire collection minus the last 30, making it dynamic?

---

**Detail:**

The reason I need to do this is because it's a chat app, and the messages need to return oldest to newest hence `sort({sent:1})` but the collection can get big and I only want to send 30 documents.

So for example

```
[
    {sent: 1, message:'hey'},
    {sent: 2, message:'sup'},
    {sent: 3, message:'nttn much'}
]
```

For this example I want to send 1 message to the client, statically it could look like this.

```
models.Message.find({ chat_id: req.params.chat_id }).skip(2).limit(1).sort({sent:1}).exec(function(err, message) {
    if(err) {
        res.json({error: 'Message not found.'});
    } else {
        res.json(message);
    }
});
```

That will return the latest `{sent: 3, message:'nttn much'}`, this is good.

BUT without the skip method it would look like this

```
models.Message.find({ chat_id: req.params.chat_id }).limit(1).sort({sent:1}).exec(function(err, message) {
    if(err) {
        res.json({error: 'Message not found.'});
    } else {
        res.json(message);
    }
});
```

returning this to the client `{sent: 1, message:'hey'}`, not so good.

So obviously I need to skip, I need to do more scouring on the mongoDB docs, but there has to be a way to check the collection length then minus `x` or in this case about 30, then pass that in to `skip()`?

Any idea how I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `skip(80).limit(30).sort({sent:-1})` to get last 30 documents, then in your client-side-app sort it with the way you wanted.

Comment: I like that and considered it, but at the same time feel like I want to handle it all server side, I am realizing that after querying the DB `message` is an object array, so I can use vanilla JS to remove objects from the  object array, then `res.json` a new object array. Working on that now..

Answer (score 0):

So I realized I can work with the object after querying the DB before doing `res.json` and sending to the client. Here is what I came up with, and seems to work as of now.

```
getById: function(req, res) {
    if (req.user) {
        models.Message.find({ chat_id: req.params.chat_id }).sort({sent:1}).exec(function(err, message) {
            if(err) {
                res.json({error: 'Message not found.'});
            } else {
                console.log(message.length);
                message = message.slice(message.length - 30);
                console.log(message);
                res.json(message);
            }
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: Probably should rename `message` to `messages` but if anyone has any comment on why the above isn't ideal I am all ears.